# Object relationship and class relationship?

Tags: java

Can anyone explain me  the difference between them? A Lake, A Fish, A Plant and A Frog. What is the Object relationship between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to awoodland's answer, a Lake object will **contain** fish, plant and frog objects. Please see [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In your example a lake is a habitat, whilst fish, plant and frog are all examples of life forms that would live in *a specific* lake.

Answer (score 2):

HAS-A and IS-A are terms used to describe object relationships. A lake HAS-A: fish, plant, and a frog. This means that your lake class contains references to a: fish, frog, and plant object. A IS-A relationship is like...a trout IS-A fish, so you extend a fish class to make a trout class.

EDIT: a frog and a fish COULD extend an animal class (since they're both animals). This is another example of an IS-A relationship

Comment: may be the typo mistake.. in the second line, it will be "your lake class contains refernces to a fish, frog and plant object" instead of "your fish class contains references to a fish, frog and plant"

Comment: Good catch, appreciate it. Changing now